# Create a table matrix for roles and permissions using JSON using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want a create a Table matrix for roles and permissions using JSON using Jquery. The table should have check boxes and the roles and permissions mapping cell should be checked if the value is present in JSON.

This is my JSON format:

```
var obj = [
  { 
    "WidgetID": 1,
    "WidgetName": "Widget 1  ",
    "ProjectRoleGroup": "Role Group 1"
  },
  { 
    "WidgetID": 1,
    "WidgetName": "Widget 1  ",
    "ProjectRoleGroup": "Role Group 2"
  },
  { 
    "WidgetID": 2,
    "WidgetName": "Widget 2",
    "ProjectRoleGroup": "Role Group 3"
  },
  { 
    "WidgetID": 3,
    "WidgetName": "Widget 3",
    "ProjectRoleGroup": "Role Group 2"
  },
  { 
    "WidgetID": 4,
    "WidgetName": "Widget 4",
    "ProjectRoleGroup": "Role Group 3"
  }
]
```

This is the table I want using Jquery:

[image]

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: my proxy block the image, can you post the html you expect? And a bit of code you're working with too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use code snippet below. There are 3 steps:

1. Get all roles (use later on the table header)
2. Merge dataSource (the buildTableDataSource function) to build data rows
3. Build the table

   ```
   <table id="tblRoles"></table>

   <script>
   var obj = [
     {
         "WidgetID": 1,
         "WidgetName": "Widget 1  ",
         "ProjectRoleGroup": "Role Group 1"
     },
     {
         "WidgetID": 1,
         "WidgetName": "Widget 1  ",
         "ProjectRoleGroup": "Role Group 2"
     },
     {
         "WidgetID": 2,
         "WidgetName": "Widget 2",
         "ProjectRoleGroup": "Role Group 3"
     },
     {
         "WidgetID": 3,
         "WidgetName": "Widget 3",
         "ProjectRoleGroup": "Role Group 2"
     },
     {
         "WidgetID": 4,
         "WidgetName": "Widget 4",
         "ProjectRoleGroup": "Role Group 3"
     }
   ]
   var getAllRoles = function () {
       var roleGroups = [];
       $.each(obj, function (i, v) {
           if (roleGroups.indexOf(v.ProjectRoleGroup) == -1) {
               roleGroups.push(v.ProjectRoleGroup);
           }
       });
       return roleGroups;
   }

   var buildTableDataSource = function () {
       var ret = [];
       $.each(obj, function (i, v) {
           var existed = $.grep(ret, function (e, i) {
               return e.WidgetID == v.WidgetID;
           });
           if (existed.length) {
               existed[0].Roles.push(v.ProjectRoleGroup);
           } else {
               ret.push({
                   WidgetID: v.WidgetID,
                   WidgetName: v.WidgetName,
                   Roles: [v.ProjectRoleGroup]
               });
           }
       });
       return ret;
   }
   var buildTable = function () {
       var allRoles = getAllRoles();
       var tableDataSource = buildTableDataSource();
       var headerRow = $("<tr><td>Permission</td></tr>");
       $.each(allRoles, function (i, v) {
           headerRow.append('<td>' + v + '</td>');
       });
       $('#tblRoles').append(headerRow);
       $.each(tableDataSource, function (i, v) {
           var row = $('<tr><td>' + v.WidgetName + '</td></tr>');
           $.each(allRoles, function (j, r) {
               if (v.Roles.indexOf(r) > -1) {
                   row.append('<td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>');
               } else {
                   row.append('<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>');
               }
               $('#tblRoles').append(row);
           });
       });
   }

   $(document).ready(function () {
       buildTable();
   })
   ```

Comment: Thanks alot @Duc Bui. It really helped. But I am getting repeated rows, like for "widget 1" I am getting 2 rows. Can you please help me on that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check that duplicate. Just updated :)

Comment: Thanks @Duc Bui. This is exactly what I wanted :)